# How to have a particular page in StackNavigator linked on a Drawer Navigator React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack navigator which has multiple pages inside and a drawer navigator which has multiple stack navigators inside. See code below.

Drawer.js

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeStack from './HomeStack';
import SampleStack from './SampleStack';

export default DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    Sample: SampleStack,  
});
```

Homestack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import newPage from '../pages/newPage';

export default HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    newPage: newPage,
});
```

How would I add a link on the drawer navigator to link to the newPage. Right now it can only link to the first item on the stack navigator. I want to keep the newPage on the HomeStack as it will be linking with mostly other HomeStack items. Or is there no way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To display your own "navigation link" in the drawer, you will need to use custom `contentComponent` that will render the links to `HomeStack` and `SampleStack` as well as your custom link. The usage is documented here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#drawernavigatorconfig and includes an example.